# Merge huge number of files into one file by reading the files in ascending order

Tags: bash, unix, merge, concatenation, xargs

I want to merge a large number of files into a single file and this merge file should happen based on ascending order of the file name. I have tried the below command and it works as intended but the only problem is that after the merge the output.txt file contains whole data in a single line because all the input files have only one line of data without any newline.

Is there any way to merge each file data into output.txt as separate line rather than merging every file data into a single line?

My list of files has the naming format of `9999_xyz_1.json`, `9999_xyz_2.json`, `9999_xyz_3.json`, ....., `9999_xyz_12000.json`.

Example:

```
$ cat 9999_xyz_1.json
abcdef
$ cat 9999_xyz_2.json
12345
$ cat 9999_xyz_3.json
Hello
```

Expected output.txt:

```
abcdef
12345
Hello
```

Actual output:

```
$ ls -d -1 -v  "$PWD/"9999_xyz_*.json | xargs cat
abcdef12345
```

### **EDIT:**

Since my input files won't contain any spaces or special characters like backslash or quotes, I decided to use the below command which is working for me as expected.

```
find . -name '9999_xyz_*.json' -type f | sort -V | xargs awk 1 > output.txt
```

Tried with file name containing a space and below are the results with 2 different commands.

Example:

```
$ cat 9999_xyz_1.json
abcdef
$ cat 9999_ xyz_2.json      -- This File name contains a space
12345
$ cat 9999_xyz_3.json
Hello
```

Expected output.txt:

```
abcdef
12345
Hello
```

Command:

```
find . -name '9999_xyz_*.json' -print0 -type f | sort -V | xargs -0 awk 1 > output.txt
```

Output:

Successfuly completed the merge as expected but with an error at the end.

```
abcdef
12345
hello

awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `
' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Command:

Here I have used the sort with -zV options to avoid the error occured in the above command.

```
find . -name '9999_xyz_*.json' -print0 -type f | sort -zV | xargs -0 awk 1 > output.txt
```

Output:

Command completed successfully but results are not as expected. Here the file name having space is treated as last file after the sort. The expectation is that the file name with space should be at second position after the sort.

```
abcdef
hello
12345
```

Comment: merging json files at the character level, can't produce a valid json file. At least you would need each json file content to be child of a parent data structure, likely some map array. This needs a json parser.

Comment: Hi Léa Gris, my concern is about the merge of files but not the type of data the file contains. Data from multiple files should be concatenated to a single file in multiple lines but not in a single line.

Comment: Do you need double newline between each file? If one newline is enough then this would probably do `shopt -s extglob; cat 9999_xyz_+([[:digit:]]).json >output.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a `for` loop, and use `echo` to add the newline between each file:

```sh
for x in `ls -v -1 -d "$PWD/"9999_xyz_*.json`; do
   cat $x
   echo
done > output.txt
```

Now, someone will invariably comment that you should never parse the output of `ls`, but I'm not sure how else to sort the files in the right order, so I kept your original `ls` command to enumerate the files, which worked according to your question.

**EDIT**

You can optimize this a lot by using `awk 1` as @oguzismail did in his answer:

```
ls -d -1 -v  "$PWD/"9999_xyz_*.json | xargs awk 1 > output.txt
```

This solution finishes in 4 seconds on my machine, with 12000 files as in your question, while the for loop takes 13 minutes to run. The difference is that the `for` loop launches 12000 `cat` processes, while the `xargs` needs only a handful to `awk` processes, which is a lot more efficient.

Note: if want to you upvote this, make sure to upvote @oguzismail's answer too, since using `awk 1` is his idea. But his answer with `printf` and `sort -V` is safer, so you probably want to use that solution anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't parse the output of ls.

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you for performing as expected. :) But seriously, do you know a way to get `*.json` to order the files the same way as `ls -v`?

Comment: Yep, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use an array instead.

```
for fname in 9999_xyz_*.json; do
  index="${fname##*_}"
  index="${index%.json}"
  files[index]="$fname"
done && awk 1 "${files[@]}" > output.txt
```

Another approach that relies on GNU extensions:

```
printf '%s\0' 9999_xyz_*.json | sort -zV | xargs -0 awk 1 > output.txt
```

Comment: This is dangerous if you run it twice in a row over a different set of files, it will remember that last set of file names for the indices that are not rewritten.

Comment: It works, but it's really not very elegant, all that filename parsing, and assuming what they look like. This really does not convince me to not parse `ls`.

Comment: @joanis added another approach

Comment: I like the `sort -zV` option better, that's a lot nicer that creating an array.

Comment: By the way, can you explain what `awk 1` does? It never ceases to amaze me how many different ways one can use Awk to do weird things, someday I might learn to master it. Meanwhile, Google helped me answer [what does `awk 1 file` mean?](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/84889-what-does-awk-1-file-mean.html)

Comment: @joanis yeah, but we still lack a POSIX compliant solution to this

Comment: Oh boy, POSIX compliance is always a high bar... But it would be nice to meet it, I agree.